# Abrir o editar php.ini en mac Os

Tags: php, html5, apache

Alguien me puede decir como abrir el archivo `php.ini`, según mi `PHP version 7.2.2` el archivo se encuentra en esta direccion:

> ./usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini

ya ingresé desde la terminal hasta la carpeta `lib` ahora como le digo que me abra el archivo `php.ini`?, casi no se utilizar la terminal alguien podría ayudarme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede editarlo utilizando el editor en el terminal y usar el comando sudo para abrirlo como superusuario, consulte [aquí](https://www.sudo.ws/man/sudo.man.html).

```
sudo vim php.ini
```

o

```
sudo emacs php.ini
```

Queda a tú elección.

Comment: muchas gracias si me funciono lo de sudo vim php.ini

Comment: @Alejandro.C me alegra, si le ha funcionado, no olvide calificar la respuesta, Saludos!

Comment: de que mandera la califico? esque soy nuevo aqui

Comment: MIra esto como [Aceptar la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y como [votar a favor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) , En la parte izquierda de mi respuesta tienes dos flechas una hacia arriba para votar a favor y una hacia abajo para votar en contra, Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Usa el comando:

```
vi php.ini
```

Dentro de `vi` pulsas a, entras en modo edicion edita el archivo, 
luego para salir **esc :wq!** eso graba el archivo y listo!